# Customized full control permission setting for sharepoint online 2013 sitecollection

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have customized the full control setting by uncheck the manage web site for hide the site clouse and deletion option from the user.

But because of this user also lost some more access. Any way to hide only site closure and deletion policies option from user?

Answer (score 0):

In current SharePoint Online, there is no option to get this approach.